# Match case not behaving the same as Regex.findAll

Tags: regex, scala, debugging

I have a little helper method, which has to normalize some money values. Hence, I wrote some regular expressions, which should detect different ways of representing them. Strangely they only trigger if used with Regex.findAllIn(..), but not if used in a match case statement.

```
val result = extractAmount("23772.90")

def extractAmount(amountStr: String): BigDecimal = {
  val Plain = """^\d+$""".r
  val Dot = """^(\d+)\.(\d*)$""".r
  val Comma = """^(\d+),(\d*)$""".r
  val DotComma = """^(\d+)\.(\d+),(\d*)$""".r
  val CommaDot = """^(\d+),(\d+)\.(\d*)$""".r

  if (Dot.findAllIn(amountStr).hasNext)
    println(Dot.findAllIn(amountStr).next())

  amountStr match {
    case Plain(value) => new java.math.BigDecimal(value)
    case Dot(values) => new BigDecimal(s"${values(0)}.${values(1)}")
    case Comma(values) => new BigDecimal(s"${values(0)}.${values(1)}")
    case DotComma(values) => new BigDecimal(s"${values(0)}${values(1)}.${values(2)}")
    case CommaDot(values) => new BigDecimal(s"${values(0)}${values(1)}.${values(2)}")
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Money amount string -->${amountStr}<-- did not match any pattern.")
  }
}
```

Debugger output hitting Regex.findAllIn(..):
[image: debugger screen shot 1]

Debugger output not hitting the match case for Dot(values):
[image: debugger screen shot 2]

Also interesting might be following error message in the debugger:
[image: Debugger error message]

Using scala version 2.11.8.

I am puzzled, for sure overlooking something obvious. Thankful for a hint.

Comment: Please use code snippets instead of screenshots. It will help contributors to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @maasg: just added a code snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing e.g.

```
case Dot(values) => new BigDecimal(s"${values(0)}.${values(1)}")
```

rewrite the usage of your `Regex` extractors like this:

```
case Dot(a, b) => new BigDecimal(s"$a.$b")
```

The amount of arguments in each extractor must match the amount of groups your regex contains (here: 2). Each argument is just a string that represents the content of one single group.

Comment: I expected it to be something easy :) thanks for the tipp. In general error messages in Scala are helpful, this time not that much...